# SharePoint Online Audit for Site Owners

Tags: sharepoint-online, auditing, reporting

This is a general question about SharePoint Online Audit/reporting for Site Owners

As a Site Owners What ability do we have to audit who has been given access to files and folders on the SharePoint site? This doesn’t pertain to the actual list of SharePoint site members, but rather to files and folders that have been shared outside externally

Answer (score 0):

You can use the audit log reports provided with SharePoint to view the data in the audit logs for a site collection. You can sort, filter, and analyze this data to determine who has done what with sites, lists, libraries, content types, list items, and library files in the site collection. For example, you can determine who deleted which content.

The following events are available for audit log reports to help you determine who is taking what actions with the content of a site collection:

Opened and downloaded documents, viewed items in lists, or viewed item properties (This event is not available for SharePoint Online sites)

Edited items

Checked out and checked in items

Items that have been moved and copied to other location in the site collection

Deleted and restored items

Changes to content types and columns

Search queries

Changes to user accounts and permissions

Changed audit settings and deleted audit log events

Workflow events

Custom events

For more information refer the below link,

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/view-audit-log-reports-b37c5869-1b47-4a82-a30d-ea20070fe527

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-a9920c97-38c0-44f2-8bcb-4cf1e2ae22d2

Answer (score 0):

This helps in finding the report 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sharing-reports